# using eigen with android ndk

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, eigen

Has anybody successfully imported the eigen library using the ndk?  I was thinking about using it to do all the math matrix operations for an app Im working on. I found a few people mentioning it in some forums but aside from the fact that I dont know if they successfully got it working most of the forums I read start off mentioning some error related to neon code.....which I havent messed with before either.

What would be really helpful is if some one can point me towards a tutorial on how to compile an existing library like eigen using the ndk. That way I can just do it for myself later on. I just now found this: http://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/ and would like to try to implement it myself but not sure where to start. Obviously I have some semi-intense reading ahead of me so Ill start that but mean time if some one could jump in and help with the compiling of native libraries for use with the ndk I would much appreciate it.

Comment: So after playing a bit with cmake I have yet to get anything to compile mostly because Im not sure how to use the command line to set variables like it says to do in the tutorial. Id have to say for some one thats not an avid command line user that those tutorials included with the android-cmake are really really vague when describing how to set things up. The author assumes you already know how to use everything and leaves out plenty of detail. I also found this while looking for documentation on getting the eigen working: https://bitbucket.org/erublee/eigen-android. it looks promising

Comment: Eigen is header only, there is no need to compile it. The cmake script only compiles the tests and creates the doxygen documentation.

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting :) so how would I go about using Eigen with the ndk then. Do I just copy the eigen source into my android project somewhere in the jni folder and then the name of what Im using in the android.mk or application.mk file? If thats how it works what would I have to declare in my mk files.  If you cant tell Im not exactly a command line or gnu guru ;) so my knowledge of doing anything outside of ms visual studio or an ide is kind of limited.

Comment: Just add the include directory to the compiler with -I ( -I/path/to/eigen )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used the Android NDK before, I'm using Eigen for numeric calculations in physics.

Eigen is header only, so you can put it every where you like. You just have to set the include path to that folder( probably inside your Android.mk ). If you don't need the unsupported libraries in Eigen, then you only need the "Eigen" folder. The rest is only for documentation, and tests.
After a short look at the documentation i think you can achieve that with

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := path/to/eigen
```

inside your Android.mk

A quick and dirty solution would be to throw Eigen inside the 'jni' folder. But this only works  if all the source using Eigen is there as well. This way you don't have to edit your Android.mk.

Comment: :) Ok Im pretty sure I understand. So Im gonna run this by you really quick before I try this......so in my make file I just declare to include the eigen library files in my build? I know that I have to #include any headers I plan on using but Im just unsure how to make sure that the actual eigen source files end up in my project so that I can use them. I dont mind the quick and dirty you mentioned being that the whole eigen library is only about 1.8 mb so I could just cut anything out I dont really need like tests and stuff.

Comment: when you've got a #include <whatever> inside your code, then the preprocessor searches this file and pastes it's content into your code. The Preprocessor looks for that file in your local folder and every folder in it's search path. You don't need to specify the Eigen files in the makefile because they don't get compiled. You just have to make sure the preprocessor finds them.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot :) your suggestions really cleared up what I should do to get things working. When I put it together and see it working Ill post back with what I did to get it all running in my app :)

Comment: So I finally just got the ndk to notice the library by importing the Eigen files right into my jni folder. Not exactly the way I was wanting to go about it but it definitely works. Now I just have to clean up my funky c++ code and Ill be good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have the Eigen headers **outside the Eclipse workspace**, just like stl etc. To do this, unzip your Eigen download and copy the folder "Eigen" into a directory of your choice:

> /Users/foo/libraries/eigen/Eigen

Then, in your project's **Android.mk** file, tell ndk-build where the Eigen include files are:

> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/foo/libraries/eigen

Don't reference the actual "Eigen" folder here, reference the folder above it, otherwise the includes won't work. Finally, tell the eclipse indexer about the includes:

> Right-click your project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> GNU C++ -> Add... -> File System... -> again point it to /Users/foo/libraries/eigen

Done.